# Determining if a URI is valid using Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, escaping

For an application I'm developing I need a Perl script which loops through a massive CSV file and ensures that every single line contains a valid URI. I already asked a question earlier about parsing a CSV file and I have started using `Text::CSV` to make my life a lot easier. Now I have the issue of ensuring that the URI is valid.

Due to the nature of my application, URIs do not need to take the full form of

```
protocol://username:password@domain.extension/request?vars=values
```

Rather I am only interested in the request portion of this. For a general website, that would be anything after the `.com`, `.edu`, etc.

I currently have the following Perl script:

```
if($_ !~ /^(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*$/i){
    print "Invalid URL format";
    exit;
} else {
    /* stuff */
}
```

The regex should be fairly straight-forward. The request is allowed to contain either one of a small set of symbols (`[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:/?@]`) or it may contain a percent sign (`%`) followed by two hexadecimal digits. Either of these patterns may be repeated indefinitely.

When I run this script I get the following error:

```
Number found where operator expected at ./301rules.pl line 58, near "%[0"
        (Missing operator before 0?)
Bareword found where operator expected at ./301rules.pl line 58, near "9A"
        (Missing operator before A?)
Bareword found where operator expected at ./301rules.pl line 58, near "$/i"
        (Missing operator before i?)
syntax error at ./301rules.pl line 58, near "%[0"
```

It's fairly obvious that something in my regex needs to be escaped, however I'm unsure of what. I tried escaping **every** possible symbol to create the following regex:

```
if($_ !~ /^(?:[a-z0-9\-\.\_\~\!\$\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\;\=\:\/\?\@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*$/i){
```

However when I did this it just allowed **every** string to pass the test, even strings which I knew are invalid such as `te%st` or `é`

So does anyone have experience with Perl regex and know what I need to escape and what I should not escape? With 19 different symbols I don't feel like trying all 2^19 = 524288 possibilities.

EDIT - voting to close. I found out that the issue actually existed immediately above this loop, although I don't entirely understand why yet.

I had:

```
if( $_ == "" ){
    next;
}
/* regex conditional from above */
```

For whatever reason it kept evaluating to true and going to the next iteration despite there clearly being data stored in `$_`. I'll figure out why this was, but for now the regex works fine with everything escaped.

Comment: String comparison is done in Perl with `eq` operator and not with `==`

Comment: `EXPR1 == EXPR2` is a numerical comparison, basically equivalent to `(0+EXPR1) == (0+EXPR2)`. You would have gotten warnings if you had them on!

Comment: The specific question asked received a couple of good answers.  Just because you asked a question that isn't relevant to your assumed problem doesn't mean the question isn't a good question, applicable to someone, nor that it wasn't specifically answered.  I wouldn't vote to close, but it's your post.

Comment: @DavidO Was going back through all my questions without accepted answers and you're right. I accepted the answer that had a simple and valid RegEx without unnecessary extra information or incorrect information. Also going to add a comment to their response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you got to your first regex, but I'll try helping you fix that. You only have to escape the characters that have special meaning in regex - from your regex, they are: -,.,$,(,),*,/, so the regex should look like:

```
if($_ !~ /^(?:[a-z0-9\-\._~!\$&'\(\)\*+,;=:\/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*$/i){
```

I don't exactly know what `?:` is trying to achieve there, but your first character class that is just following it (the expression between the first `[]` ) is not having any multipliers - maybe it should be followed by a *, a +, or a ?. Also, the `|` sign I think is meant to do the `or` between your first character class and the second character class preceded by a `%` - as it looks right now, it does it beteween the first character class and the `%` sign only. It probably should be like `|(%[0-9A-F]{2}))*$`

Comment: The regex was actually created just by looking up what symbols do not have to be escaped in a URL (most symbols, like space for instance, must be escaped (`%20`)). I wanted to say "either a non-escaped symbol OR (%XX)" (where XX is hexadecimal). I will put the `%[0-9A-F]{2}` in parenthesis now that you pointed out it is not all considered in the or statement. As for the `?:`, http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html this should explain it. Essentially it speeds up the regular expression and uses less memory by disabling back referencing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out what `?:` is used for. However, optimizing for performance a regex that is not working is called premature optimization and only make things harder to debug :)

Comment: I've actually discovered that within square brackets (`[` and `]`) you do not need to escape *most* RegEx characters. The only one character that needed to be escaped was `/`, since that terminates the RegEx early. Otherwise within square brackets many symbols such as `?`, `$`, `(`, `)`, etc. lose their meaning.

Answer (score 5):

In the documentation for the [`URI` module](http://p3rl.org/URI) I found the following:

> PARSING URIs WITH REGEXP
>
> As an alternative to this module, the
>   following (official) regular
>   expression can be used to decode a
>   URI:
>
> ```
>     my($scheme, $authority, $path,
>     $query, $fragment) =   $uri =~
>     m|(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?|;
> ```
>
> The URI::Split module provides the
>   function uri_split() as a readable alternative.

But I think [Regexp::Common::URI](http://p3rl.org/Regexp%3a%3aCommon%3a%3aURI) is probably an ideal solution for syntax validation of an HTTP URI.

```
use Regexp::Common qw /URI/;
while (<>) {
    /$RE{URI}{HTTP}/  and  print "Contains an HTTP URI.\n";
}
```

Anything written by Damian and maintained by Abigail has got to be either inspired, great, crazy, or all of the above. (And I mean that with the highest possible regard).

Comment: But my question wasn't about splitting or parsing a URI. I just had to look at the request portion of the URI (everything following the domain and before the GET variables) and determine if it consisted of valid characters. Thank you for the research, but it was irrelevant to my question. However I have already voted to close the question as I found the error existed elsewhere in my code.

Comment: for some reason it does not catch this type of URI's: https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=eu-west-1#Instances . So I end-up using the text2html func from here: http://www.dispersiondesign.com/articles/perl/converting_text_to_html

Answer (score -1):

You should use rfc regexp for checking *EVERY* possible character. Look at [this](http://www.mattfarina.com/2009/01/08/rfc-3986-url-validation)